# Instance member 'setData' cannot be used on type 'PreviewView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Here is my code and I'm getting the error..Please check n let me know how to resolve this.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
{
        guard let customMarkerView = marker.iconView as? CustomMarkerView else {  
              return nil }
        let data = previewDemoData[customMarkerView.tag]
        PreviewView.setData(title: data.title, img: data.img) // Error
        return restaurantPreviewView
}
```

Comment: It's what the error says. You need to create an **instance** of `PreviewView` instead of using the class name.

Comment: `setData` is *not* static, you have to create an instance of `PreviewView` and then use it to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

PreviewView is your class and I think you have an instance variable: `var restaurantPreviewView : PreviewView!`

```
PreviewView.setData(title: data.title, img: data.img) // Error
```

You should use something like that:

```
restaurantPreviewView.setData(title: data.title, img: data.img)
```